# Was ExtensionSidebarPane broken in Chrome 92 upgrade?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I released a Chrome DevTools extension a couple years ago that uses
chrome.devtools.panels.elements.createSidebarPane(title, callback)
to add an ExtensionSidebarPane. This worked fine until Chrome 92. Now the Pane is created with the title, but it is blank.

The calls I am using are still documented: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/devtools_panels/, but the example code that I used has been moved to into the mv2-archive section of the google-extension-samples repo. And the [chrome-query example code](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples/blob/e716678b67fd30a5876a552b9665e9f847d6d84b/mv2-archive/api/devtools/panels/chrome-query/devtools.js) no longer works either. So maybe that means it is unsupported now. On the other hand, [everything I have found so far](https://www.reddit.com/r/vivaldibrowser/comments/kapnif/manifest_v2_to_remain_throughout_2021/) seems to say v2 should be supported to the end of 2021. And I haven't found any alternative v3 examples of adding info to the devtools UI.

Obviously createSidebarPane is getting called, because the blank pane is created with the expected title. And intentionally throwing an error in the callback shows that it is getting called with the expected ExtensionSidebarPane object as a parameter, it's just that calling setExpression or setObject on it doesn't do anything. I am not seeing any other errors or warnings.

I would hate to retire my extension, since I know people use it, but I am not sure what else to try.

Comment: Probably https://crbug.com/1233027

Comment: Seems like it. Both setObject and setExpression are broken. Though, setPage works.

Comment: It's working again, btw. I think it was fixed in Chrome 95.